# ethtool -m in windows (SFP Digital Optical Monitoring - DOM)

Tags: windows, fiber

I am running 10 Gbit optical link on Intel X520 on Windows in home lab. I plan to do some experiments with the fiber and it would be interesting to see SFP transceiver Digital Optical Monitoring (DOM) readings in windows, similar to ethtool -m in Linux. Is there a way to achieve that? Are there any other NIC chipsets allowing easier DOM access in windows?

Already tried WSL2, but surely NIC inside WSL2 is virtual.

I need to get something like this:

```
cumulus@switch$ sudo ethtool -m swp3
    Identifier                                : 0x03 (SFP)
    Extended identifier                       : 0x04 (GBIC/SFP defined by 2-wire interface ID)
    Connector                                 : 0x07 (LC)
    Transceiver codes                         : 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x20 0x40 0x0c 0x05
    Transceiver type                          : Ethernet: 1000BASE-SX
    Transceiver type                          : FC: intermediate distance (I)
    Transceiver type                          : FC: Shortwave laser w/o OFC (SN)
    Transceiver type                          : FC: Multimode, 62.5um (M6)
    Transceiver type                          : FC: Multimode, 50um (M5)
    Transceiver type                          : FC: 200 MBytes/sec
    Transceiver type                          : FC: 100 MBytes/sec
    Encoding                                  : 0x01 (8B/10B)
    BR, Nominal                               : 2100MBd
    Rate identifier                           : 0x00 (unspecified)
    Length (SMF,km)                           : 0km
    Length (SMF)                              : 0m
    Length (50um)                             : 300m
    Length (62.5um)                           : 150m
    Length (Copper)                           : 0m
    Length (OM3)                              : 0m
    Laser wavelength                          : 850nm
    Vendor name                               : JDSU
    Vendor OUI                                : 00:01:9c
    Vendor PN                                 : PLRXPL-VI-S24-22
    Vendor rev                                : 1
    Optical diagnostics support               : Yes
    Laser bias current                        : 21.348 mA
    Laser output power                        : 0.3186 mW / -4.97 dBm
    Receiver signal average optical power     : 0.3195 mW / -4.96 dBm
    Module temperature                        : 41.70 degrees C / 107.05 degrees F
    Module voltage                            : 3.2947 V
    Alarm/warning flags implemented           : Yes
    Laser bias current high alarm             : Off
    Laser bias current low alarm              : Off
    Laser bias current high warning           : Off
    Laser bias current low warning            : Off
    Laser output power high alarm             : Off
    Laser output power low alarm              : Off
    Laser output power high warning           : Off
    Laser output power low warning            : Off
    Module temperature high alarm             : Off
    Module temperature low alarm              : Off
    Module temperature high warning           : Off
    Module temperature low warning            : Off
    Module voltage high alarm                 : Off
    Module voltage low alarm                  : Off
    Module voltage high warning               : Off
    Module voltage low warning                : Off
    Laser rx power high alarm                 : Off
    Laser rx power low alarm                  : Off
    Laser rx power high warning               : Off
    Laser rx power low warning                : Off
    Laser bias current high alarm threshold   : 10.000 mA
    Laser bias current low alarm threshold    : 1.000 mA
    Laser bias current high warning threshold : 9.000 mA
    Laser bias current low warning threshold  : 2.000 mA
    Laser output power high alarm threshold   : 0.8000 mW / -0.97 dBm
    Laser output power low alarm threshold    : 0.1000 mW / -10.00 dBm
    Laser output power high warning threshold : 0.6000 mW / -2.22 dBm
    Laser output power low warning threshold  : 0.2000 mW / -6.99 dBm
    Module temperature high alarm threshold   : 90.00 degrees C / 194.00 degrees F
    Module temperature low alarm threshold    : -40.00 degrees C / -40.00 degrees F
    Module temperature high warning threshold : 85.00 degrees C / 185.00 degrees F
    Module temperature low warning threshold  : -40.00 degrees C / -40.00 degrees F
    Module voltage high alarm threshold       : 4.0000 V
    Module voltage low alarm threshold        : 0.0000 V
    Module voltage high warning threshold     : 3.6450 V
    Module voltage low warning threshold      : 2.9550 V
    Laser rx power high alarm threshold       : 1.6000 mW / 2.04 dBm
    Laser rx power low alarm threshold        : 0.0100 mW / -20.00 dBm
    Laser rx power high warning threshold     : 1.0000 mW / 0.00 dBm
    Laser rx power low warning threshold      : 0.0200 mW / -16.99 dBm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WSL1 will let you see the real hardware.

From [Comparing WSL Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions) :

> If you rely on a Linux distribution to have an IP address in the same network as your host machine, you may need to set up a workaround in order to run WSL 2. WSL 2 is running as a hyper-v virtual machine. This is a change from the bridged network adapter used in WSL 1, meaning that WSL 2 uses a Network Address Translation (NAT) service for it's virtual network, instead of making it bridged to the host Network Interface Card (NIC) resulting in a unique IP address that will change on restart.

WSL2 is essentially running inside a Hyper-V virtual machine.
Its network interface, as in all virtual machines is, well, virtual.
As a result, WSL2 doesn't see your physical network cards.

Comment: I guess there is no other way, other than dual booting... Unfortunately I really need WSL2 features, so I'll probably have to boot into different os. Unexpected that there is no solution in windows.

Comment: I am trying this on windows 11 and it results in `Cannot get module EEPROM information: Invalid argument` when i do `ethtool -m <interface name>` in wsl1.

I know the transceiver is DOM capable as i have one in my router and can query it.